# Storing Comments Of PPM File In Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, comments, storing-data, ppm

I am trying to read a PPM File and store the comments in a linked list so far I have created a structure of Node with value and struct pointer to next node. Also created an append function and also a print linked list function. But when I try to call the function in main it doesn't print anything.

```
struct Node{
     char value;
     struct Node *next;
};

void append(struct Node * headNode, int newElement){
     struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); //Dynamically Allocating Memory for New Node
     struct Node *tailNode = headNode;                   //Creating A Tail Node to traverse the linked list

     newNode->value = newElement;                        //Assigning the values of newNode to the given value
     newNode->next = NULL;                               //Setting next value to be null since its the last node

     if (headNode == NULL){                              //Checking if headnode is empty
     headNode = newNode;                             //Assigning headnode and tailnode to be newnode
     tailNode = newNode;
     }

     while(tailNode->next != NULL){                      //Traversing through the linked list
          tailNode = tailNode->next;
     }

     tailNode->next = newNode;                           //Setting tailnode's next to be newnode
     tailNode = newNode;   
}

void printLinkedList(struct Node* headNode){
     while(headNode != NULL){
        printf("%d",headNode->value);
        headNode = headNode->next;
        }
   }

struct Node* getComments(char *filename){
    struct Node *headNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    FILE *f = fopen(filename,"r");
    int ch = getc(f);
        while(ch == '#'){
            while(ch != '\n'){
                append(headNode,ch);
                ch = getc(f);
            }
        }
    return headNode;
}
```

Also My comments are a string but in printLinked List when I use "%s" it says argument is int even though i specified as char.

This is the main Function

```
void main(int argc, char * argv[]){
     printLinkedList(getComments(argv[1]);
}
```

A PPM Files Starts Like This

```
P3
# 100 * 100  square
100 100
255
..
..
```

Here the line with # is a comment.

Any Comments welcome on code

Comment: Did you manage a simpler goal, like filling a linked list with integers and printing them?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Does your file start with a "#" comment and only contains more such lines? Please show an example.

Comment: Your values are `char`, i.e. single letters. Why do you attempt to printf with `%d`? Or with `%s`?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes the comments in a ppm file start with # I have edited the question with a file example.

Comment: The comments start with "#" but the first line does not. End of your loop `while(ch == '#')`. End of your `getcomment()`. End of your program.

Comment: An interesting example of looking for an error in code, while the problem is with the expectations on the input. Kind of a useful insight. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The comment lines start with "#" but the first line of the sample file does not.
End of your loop `while(ch == '#')`.
End of your `getcomment()`.
End of your program.

I think your program has more issues. But for the described situation/input this is the explanation.